# How to specify unique geom assignments to facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-bar, facet-wrap

Below I have simulated a dataset where an assignment was given to 5 groups of individuals on 5 different days (a new group with 200 new individuals each day). `TrialStartDate` denotes the date on which the assignment was given to each individual (`ID`), and TrialEndDate denotes when each individual finished the assignment.

```r
set.seed(123)
data <- 
  data.frame(
    TrialStartDate = rep(c(sample(seq(as.Date('2019/02/01'), as.Date('2019/02/15'), by="day"), 5)), each = 200),
    TrialFinishDate = sample(seq(as.Date('2019/02/01'), as.Date('2019/02/15'), by = "day"), 1000,replace = T),
    ID = seq(1,1000, 1)
  )
```

I am interested in comparing how long individuals took to complete the trial depending on when they started the trial (i.e., assuming `TrialStartDate` has an effect on the length of time it takes to complete the trial).

To visualize this, I want to make a barplot showing counts of `ID`s on each `TrialFinishDate` where bars are colored by `TrialStartDate` (since each `TrialStartDate` acts as a grouping variable). The best I have come up with so far is by faceting like this:

```r
data%>%
  group_by(TrialStartDate, TrialFinishDate)%>%
  count()%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = TrialFinishDate, y = n,  col = factor(TrialStartDate), fill = factor(TrialStartDate)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  facet_wrap(~TrialStartDate, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

However, I also want to add a vertical line to each facet showing when the `TrialStartDate` was for each group (preferably colored the same as the bars). When attempting to add vertical lines with `geom_vline`, it adds all the lines to each facet:

```r
data%>%
  group_by(TrialStartDate, TrialFinishDate)%>%
  count()%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = TrialFinishDate, y = n,  col = factor(TrialStartDate), fill = factor(TrialStartDate)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = unique(data$TrialStartDate))+
  facet_wrap(~TrialStartDate, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

How can we make the vertical lines unique to the respective group in each facet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying xintercept outside of `aes`, so the faceting is not respected.

This should do the trick:

```
data %>%
  group_by(TrialStartDate, TrialFinishDate)%>%
  count()%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = TrialFinishDate, y = n,  col = factor(TrialStartDate), fill = factor(TrialStartDate)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = TrialStartDate))+
  facet_wrap(~TrialStartDate, ncol = 1)
```

Note `geom_vline(aes(xintercept = TrialStartDate))`